# Read Moment Full Timezone Name

Tags: javascript, typescript, timezone, momentjs

[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) provides out-of-the-box an array of great functionality.

One of it via the [timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone) add-on is to show the string abbreviation of timezone, like `CET`:

```
const locationName = moment.tz.guess(true)                       // "Europe/Berlin"
const timezoneInitials = moment.tz(locationName).format('zz')    // "CET"
```

**Is it possible to get the full timezone name string for CET (i.e. `Central European Time`) from a moment object?**

If not, what are the alternatives?

As of today, such parsing is not available/documented. Mapping and deduping from a list like [List of time zone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) doesnt seem optimal also.

Comment: I don't think so, as they suggest you can do this by overriding the `zoneName` method yourself, at https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/

Answer (score 2):

Moment doesn't offer this functionality directly.

However, most modern browsers support the ECMAScript Internationalization API, allowing you to write a function like the following:

```
function getTimeZoneLongName(date, locale, timeZone) {
  const f = Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { timeZone, timeZoneName: 'long' });
  return f.formatToParts(date).find(x => x.type === 'timeZoneName').value;
}
```

Example usages:

```
// current date/time, current locale and time zone
getTimeZoneLongName(new Date()) //=> "Pacific Standard Time"

// current date/time, specific locale, current time zone
getTimeZoneLongName(new Date(), "fr") //=> "heure normale du Pacifique nord-américain"

// current date/time, specific locale, specific time zone
getTimeZoneLongName(new Date(), "fr", "Asia/Tokyo") //=> "eure normale du Japon"

// specific date/time, current locale, specific time zone
getTimeZoneLongName(new Date(2020, 5, 1), undefined, "Europe/London") //=> "British Summer Time"
```

(Example output is from Chrome 78 on Windows 10, English, US Pacific time zone)

Note that this gives the name for either the standard time or the daylight time, depending on what is in effect for the date given.  There isn't currently a way to retrieve the generic name.

In other words, for English and `Europe/Berlin`, it will return either `"Central European Standard Time"` or `"Central European Summer Time"`, but not just `"Central European Time"`.